# A `cond` that is also a `let`?

Tags: scheme, lisp, conditional-statements, let

Frequently, I find I want to compute a series of values *conditionally* depending on the value of previous values. For example, let's call these values `x`, `y` and `z`. First I compute `x`. If `x` meets certain criteria, then I compute `y`, which is function of `x`, and so on.  Schematically,

```
;; compute value x
;; if x =? #f -> #f
;; else compute value y = f(x)
;; if y =? #f -> #f
;; else compute value z = f(y)
;; et cetera
```

How do you do this in Scheme? I think typically one would use `cond` but `cond` throws away the results of the tests, therefore it's no use in this situation.

Answer (score 7):

Use `let*`, which evaluates the initialization forms sequentially, in the scope of the brevious bindings. In the initialization forms, use `and` to make the calculation conditional.

```
(let* ((x (compute-x))
       (y (and x (f1 x)))
       (z (and y (f2 y))))
  ;; code that uses the variables
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of the `=>` device in the `cond` clauses, for example:

```
(define (testing p x)
   (if (p x) 
      x 
      #f))

(display
   (cond
      ((testing even? 1) => (lambda (x)          ; the clause is skipped
                              (list 10 x)))
      ((testing even? 2) => (lambda (x)          ; the clause is entered and
                              (list 20 x)))))    ;   `x` is bound to 2
```

You would have nested `cond`(s) in the corresponding clause(s), to represent the nested conditions like you describe.

This way the code structure manifestly follows your logic, which is always good.

Answer (score 1):

So you're code can be written like this in standard Common Lisp:

```
(let ((it x-expression))
  (if it
      (let ((it (f it)))
        (if it
            it))))
```

Notice I'm not giving an else-form (alternative) since it is optional in CL. 
Paul Graham introduces [Anaphoric macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro) in a way to automatic cache the test value.

```
(defmacro aif (test-form then-form &optional else-form)
  `(let ((it ,test-form))
     (if it ,then-form ,else-form)))

(aif x-expression
  (aif (f it)
    (aif (f it)
         it)
```

This works well in CL, but it poses problems with hygiene in Scheme. I know someone has created something with an extra parameter for the binding name, but it looses it's elegance:

```
(aif x x-expression
  (aif y (f x)
    (aif z (f y)
         z)))
```

I've been experimenting with `cond` When creating evaluators I usually test before I can peel and that ends with `if` and `let` nesting. My first iteration looked like:

```scm
(define (ev expr env)
  (defcond 
    ((symbol? expr) (symbol->value expr env))
    ((not (pair? expr)) expr => (operator (ev (car expr) env)))
    ((macro? operator) (macro-apply expr (cdr expr) env) => (args (map (lambda (e) (ev e env)) (cdr expr))))
    (else (fun-apply operator args env))))
```

It also supported an alternative way since I found it not so elegant to reuse =>:

```scm
(define (ev expr env)
  (defcond 
    ((symbol? expr) (symbol->value expr env))
    ((not (pair? expr)) expr)
    (define operator (ev (car expr) env))
    ((macro? operator) (macro-apply expr (cdr expr) env))
    (define args (map (lambda (e) (ev e env)) (cdr expr)))
    (else (fun-apply operator args env))))
```

Now this can be used in the same way as `aif` as well. If you're interested the Scheme macro is:

```scm
(define-syntax defcond
  (syntax-rules (else bind define =>)
    ((_ "build" terms ())
     terms)
    ((_ "build" alternative ((bind (b e) ...) . rest))
     (defcond "build" (let ((b e) ...) alternative) rest))
    ((_ "build" alternative ((bind name (b e) ...) . rest))
     (defcond "build" (let name ((b e) ...) alternative) rest))
    ((_ "build" alternative ((define b e) . rest))
     (defcond "build" (letrec ((b e)) alternative) rest))
    ((_ "build" alternative ((predicate consequent) . rest))
     (defcond "build" (if predicate consequent alternative) rest))
    ((_ "build" alternative ((predicate consequent => (b e) ...) . rest))
     (defcond "build" (if predicate consequent (let ((b e) ...) alternative)) rest))
    ((_ "build" alternative ((predicate consequent) . rest))
     (defcond "build" (if predicate consequent alternative) rest))
    ((_ "maybe-else" ((else expression) . rest))
     (defcond "build" expression rest))
    ((_ "maybe-else" ((something expression) . rest))
     (defcond "build" #f ((something expression) . rest)))
    ((_ "reverse" terms ())
     (defcond "maybe-else" terms))
    ((_ "reverse" (fterms ...) (term1 terms ...))
     (defcond "reverse" (term1 fterms ...) (terms ...)))
    ((_ terms ...)
     (defcond "reverse" () (terms ...)))))
```

Not very elegant implementation, but it works. As you can see it supports `bind` and named `bind` as well. eg.

```scm
(defcond 
  ((not (pair? lst)) #f)
  (bind loop ((lst lst) (acc 0)))
  ((null? lst) acc)
  (else (loop (cdr lst) (+ acc (car lst))))
```

While I like the idea I still don't think it is a divine and elegant as it should be. Until a better syntax emerges I'll be writing it for readability. eg.:

```scm
(if (not (pair? lst))
    #f
    (let loop ((lst lst) (acc 0))
      (if (null? lst)
          acc
          (loop (cdr lst) (+ acc (car lst))))))
```